# Tips on Improving Peak Analysis of a Signal. (peak widths)

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, computer-vision, signal-processing, scientific-computing

- Hi all. I've got hundreds of signals of this form on which I have
  detected peaks above some threshold.

[image]

I define a **peak width as FWHM (full width at half maximum)**. However, I've fitted a cubic polynomial to the valleys of the signal, and so I've defined a peak as the distance from this baseline at same index as the peak to the peak.

I'm calculating **peak width as the greatest distance between the intersection of the signal and a line at half the max**. It looks like this:

```
roots = indeces_of_intersections

intersection_lengths=[abs(y - x) for x, y in it.combinations(roots, 2)]

calculated_width = max(intersection_lengths)
```

I'm having problems calculating peak width consistently and that's because sometimes the line intersects with points on different peaks.

[image]

I've **restricted the domain on which this intersecting line is defined:**

*Domain = [a little to the left of the peak, a little to the right of it]*

but this domain restriction is the same for all peaks.

I've thought about somehow having this domain change for different peaks but not sure how to implement that. My code is almost fully automated, and I have to keep it that way.

[image]

Comment: Also, let me clarify: if I make the intersecting line domain too small, it won't detect the larger peaks. I have thought about implementing a line which starts at the middle and grows outward until it hits its first intersection on either side. 

Also, if I have the indices of intersections, I could find which pair is the smallest which also contains the peak index, I suppose.'

Comment: You could use spline interpolations to calculate the first and second derivative of your data, from which you can determine peaks and when a other peaks starts. If your data is noise, you could also try to use some smoothing scheme.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Those are good points, however, I already have a discrete signal so interpolating would be slower and likely to cause error. It would still be unclear to me how that would help me solve my intersection problem (which I thought was a simple way to measure widths and a problem I have now solved).

Comment: Using a [spline interpolation scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_%28mathematics%29), you will obtain piecewise polynomials, usually a single polynomial for each interval between your data points, giving you an approximated continuous function. But from this, you can look at the derivatives in each data point, and figure out if the slope is going up or down (hence a peak or valley). Unless you have gigabytes of data you want to process in realtime, I dont think you'll have performance issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my question onto here helped me realize an easy solution:

```
more_than_peak=[x for x in it.ifilter(lambda x: x if x>peaks[i] else 0, roots)]
less_than_peak=[x for x in it.ifilter(lambda x: x if x<peaks[i] else 0, roots)]
if len(more_than_peak)>0 or len(less_than_peak)>0:
     width = min(more_than_peak)-max(less_than_peak)
```

Here, I'm finding the intersections to the left and right of the peak index. Then, I'm finding the smallest one to the right of the peak and the biggest one to the left (x axis increases to the right). So simple and fast!